# Apache Karaf starts with errors - protocol_version

Tags: java, apache-karaf

I am using Java 1.7 and Apache Karaf 4.0.1. When I strat Karaf, I get the following:

> | 26 - org.apache.karaf.deployer.features - 4.0.1 | Unable to install
> features java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact
> org.apache.cxf.dosgi:cxf-dosgi:xml:features:1.7.0: Could not transfer
> artifact org.apache.cxf.dosgi:cxf-dosgi:xml:features:1.7.0 from/to
> central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/): Received fatal alert:
> protocol_version :
> mvn:org.apache.cxf.dosgi/cxf-dosgi/1.7.0/xml/features

Any ideas how I can fix this?

When I do the maven build, I try setting the TLS version:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms1024m"
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2;
```

Answer (score 1):

First - you should really stop using JDK1.7

But I understand that you may have reasons - I had them too.

So - features deployer of Karaf uses pax-url-aether, which uses aether-resolver, which uses Apache http client 4.

`"-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"` system property can be used only to configure connections obtained using `java.net.URL#openConnection()` and it won't help here.

I was however able to contact TLS 1.2 repositories in such scenario, by using BouncyCastle security provider. You have to do few things:

1. put bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar and bctls-jdk15on-1.60.jar into either $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext or any other directory like `/path/to/ext` **and** use this directory in `-Djava.ext.dirs=/path/to/ext` system property
2. prepare `java.policy` file by copying original `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` and adding:

```
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider 
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider
```

and (at the bottom of this file):

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, SSLv2Hello, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

With bouncy castle you should also NOT use `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

It worked for me and all TLS communication was done using BC provider.

EDIT: you can't use newer versions of Bouncycastle because of https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/557